# How does the teb_local_planner calculate path points for ackermann steering vehicles?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to understand whether the steering angle and vehicle velocity commands make sense from the teb_local_planner given the local path poses and orientation. Trying to get an intuitive understanding of what's going on with conventional bicycle model equations. I can't seem to get the calculations right or are the results just an approximation of the kinematic model from teb_local_planner? I am not quite certain which is the case. Appreciate any help you guys can offer!

pose0 from the local_path output should be the initial position of the vehicle.
(x,y,yaw) = (-21.87,11.4,-0.157), t_stamp=0.866s

pose1 from the local_path output should be the next position the vehicle is trying to reach.
(x,y,yaw) = (-21.78,11.39,-0.102),t_stamp=0.866s according to my understanding positive yaw is CCW

The command is applied at t_stamp=0.866s is
(cmd_vel,tire_wheel_angle) = (0.222,0.148) according to my understanding wheel_angle positive is CW

The bicycle model I am referring to is from pages 23 - 24. I would post the pictures here but my account is too new.
"Chapter 2, Lateral Vehicle Dynamics", R. Rajamani, Vehicle Dynamics and Control, Mechanical Engineering Series, https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461414322-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1265143-p174267791. (2012)https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461414322-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1265143-p174267791. (2012)

I am calculating the center of rotation from the rear axle
lf = 2.1685
lr = 0
delta_f = tire_wheel_angle from teb_local_planner
psi = yaw from teb_local_planner

From the calculations, I get the following
(d_x, d_y, d_psi) = (1.1e-2,-3.3e-3,-7.5e-4). These values are after multiplying dt =0.05

Adding these values to pose0, these don't seem to be close to pose1. If anyone could help offer any insight, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386426/how-does-the-teb_local_planner-calculate-path-points-for-ackermann-steering-vehicles?/) by [xparr45](https://answers.ros.org/users/71426/xparr45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
Very interesting question. What I am not clear is the connection to teb_local_planner calculation as you don’t show the output of such. I read in the documentation of how the Ackerman model is defined in this module so I’m not sure if you are referring to this or not.

http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
This is the code Ackermann drive to teb_local_planner to help your analysis: https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner/blob/melodic-devel/scripts/cmd_vel_to_ackermann_drive.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following paper discusses that teb planner is optimizing based on "minimizing a cost function which capturing partially conflicting objectives" . The bicycle model may be an oversimplification unless you set parameters accordingly:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Franz-Albers/publication/326233414_Online_Trajectory_Optimization_and_Navigation_in_Dynamic_Environments_in_ROS/links/5f998357458515b7cfa44985/Online-Trajectory-Optimization-and-Navigation-in-Dynamic-Environments-in-ROS.pdf?origin=publication_detail

[image: image description]

Source:
Online Trajectory Optimization and Navigation
in Dynamic Environments in ROS
Franz Albers??, Christoph R¨osmann, Frank Hoffmann and Torsten Bertram

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0